# ORACLE Database from command prompt

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have installed an Oracle 11g database and created a new table using SQL Developer, but when I try to execute the query "`SELECT * FROM testGeo`" on the command prompt, I'm told that the table doesn't exist.

Here is the script used in the command prompt :

```
SQL> connect testprojet as sysdba;
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> select * from testgeo;
select * from testgeo
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

EDIT :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [`DESCRIBE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/tools/rtoolsijcomrefdescribe.html)?

Comment: I get : SQL> describe testgeo;
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object testgeo does not exist

Comment: What if you provide fully qualified name for your table (including schema)?

Comment: How can I know the name of the schema ?

Comment: See if [this article](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:5159260510057) helps.  I do not have SQL Developer on my home computer.

Comment: You need to connect using the account `OTHMANE` - because that's the one you used to create the tables (at least, that's what your screenshot suggests)

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't be using sysdba accounts for your general database access.  Who did you log in as in SQL Developer when you created the table?  Was it OTHMANE?

To find out what schema the table lives in you can do:

```
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM all_tables
 WHERE table_name = 'TESTGEO';
```

Note that unless you put the table name inside double quotes when you create it, the database names it in upper case.

The OWNER column will tell you what schema the table is created in. At that point you can do:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM <owner>.testgeo;
```

where `<owner>` is what you identified in the query of all_tables.